# PaulFreund/xmpp receiving tags order

Tags: c#, tags, xmpp

I am writting Windows 8 chat program with PaulFreunds XMPP library - [PaulFreund/XMPP](https://github.com/PaulFreund/xmpp)

I have two problems:
First - i need to bound my resource manually. I dont know where to put bounding resource tag in code. It needs to be send when client is connecting, but i cant get to that place. After client is connected sending tag couses me a error. Tag:

```
        public void bindResource()
    {
        var iq = new XMPP.tags.jabber.client.iq();
        iq.type = XMPP.tags.jabber.client.iq.typeEnum.set;
        var bind = new XMPP.tags.xmpp_bind.bind();
        var resource = new XMPP.tags.xmpp_bind.resource();
        resource.Add("myresource");
        bind.Add(resource);
        iq.Add(bind);
        Client.Send(iq);
    }
```

Second one is also order tricky. I want to get my friend list with my request:

```
        public void getFriends()
    {
        var iq = new XMPP.tags.jabber.iq.roster.query();
        var tag = new XMPP.tags.jabber.client.iq();
        tag.type = XMPP.tags.jabber.client.iq.typeEnum.get;
        tag.Add(iq);
        Client.Send(tag);
    }
```

It works ok. But here i also want to proccess with that after i get presences about status from server. (lets call it server since we all know its from every single friend on our list) It is becouse i am setting online value in my contact list. I can do it in order like now: 1st status 2nd friend list but i need to make some cache file that i dont want to make. I tryed to put it in `OnConnected` event but presence from firends is coming to me also earlier that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library implements a state machine and should automatically send a bind request to the server once it gets to the BindingState after you started to connect, see [States](https://github.com/PaulFreund/xmpp/tree/master/states). When resource binding is successful you will receive the result via the OnReceive event.

To your second question, although it might be technically possible it is not intended. XMPP presences work on a publisher subscriber model and the client which impersonates the subscriber can not control when the publisher sends new information. Even if the server would not publish the current set of presences of your contacts upon connecting, a contact might connect at that very moment and the client would receive a presence notification. 
Roster management is an optional feature and can not replace the information you gather from presences (for example, the roster does not tell you the status of a contact).

In order to provide all information about the users contacts you need to create a data structure that holds both, the additional roster information and the presences for the contacts.

As a reference you can look at my implementation of a Windows 8 messenger [Chat](https://github.com/PaulFreund/Chat) which even though it is not perfect should give you an idea of how to manage your XMPP connections